# Bison Stack emantic value

Tags: debugging, stack, flex-lexer, bisonc++

This one is Lexical Analyzer using Flex.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>

#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()

#include "conv.tab.h"
using namespace std;

%}
eq [ \t]*=
%%

[ \t]           ;
(?:POINT|LINE)  { yylval.ename = strdup(yytext); return ENAME; }
x{eq}           { yylval.xval = atof(yytext);
                    return XVAL; }
y{eq}           { yylval.yval = atof(yytext);
                    return YVAL; }
.               ;
%%
```

And other file is Bison grammar file

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex ();
extern "C" int yyparse (void);
extern "C" FILE *yyin;
extern int line_no;

void yyerror(const char *s);

%}

%union{
    float xval;
    float yval;
    char *ename;
}

%token <ename> ENAME
%token XVAL
%token YVAL

%%

converter:
    converter ENAME { cout << "entity = " << $2 << endl; }
    | converter XVAL {// x -> xval = $2; 
      cout << "x value = " << endl; }
    | converter YVAL {// y -> yval = $2; 
       cout << "y value = " << endl; }
    | ENAME { cout << "entity = " << $1 << endl; }
    | XVAL { cout << "xvalue " << endl; }
    | YVAL { cout << "yvalue " << endl; }

%%
main() {
    FILE *myfile = fopen("conv.aj", "r");

    if (!myfile) {
            cout << "I can't open file" << endl;
            return -1;
    }

    yyin = myfile;

    do{
            yydebug = 1;
            yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
    yydebug = 2;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    cout << "Parser error! Message: " << s << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

Actually, I want to retrieve values from a file. I used the Bison Debugger and get to know that those values are not able to push onto Bison Stack. So basically I want to push those values onto the stack.My file is like :
    POINT
    x=38
    y=47

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your lexical analyzer matches a number, so the `38` and `47` from the input will both be handled by your default rule (`. ;`) which will cause them to be ignored. In your rules for `XVAL` and `YVAL`, you call `atoi` on `yytext`, which will be `x=` (or `y=`); that is clearly not a number and `atoi` will probably return `0`.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "those values are not able to push onto Bison Stack", but I think this problem has nothing to do with bison or its stack.

By the way:

1. There is no need to have two different members in your semantic type for `xval` and `yval`. The type is a `union`, not a `struct`, so having two members of the same type (`float`) is redundant.
2. `flex` doesn't do regex captures. So there is really no point avoiding a capture with `(?:...)`; it just obscures your grammar. You might as well use:

   POINT|LINE: { yylval.ename = strdup(yytext); return ENAME; }

   On the other hand, you might be better off defining two different token types, which would avoid the need for the `strdup`. (You don't seem to be `free`ing the duplicated string, so the `strdup` is also a memory leak.) Alternatively, you could use an enumerated value in your semantic type:

   ```
   POINT  { yylval.ename_enum=POINT; return ENAME; }
   LINE   { yylval.ename_enum=LINE;  return ENAME; }
   ```
3. `. ;` is not really a good idea, especially during development, because it hides errors (such as the one you have). You can use `%option nodefault` to avoid `flex`'s default rule, and then flex will present an error when an illegal character is detected.
4. Unless you're using really old versions of `bison` and `flex`, you can just compile the generated code as `c++`. There should not be a need to use `extern "C"`